# Very long loading time & crashed in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, web, loading, long-integer

I have a very strange situation.

The site, which I developed https://www.helpcheck.de/ works very well on all browsers, except the internet explorer.

There I have loading times bigger than 20seconds, and sometimes the browser crashes.

I tried the website on several pcs, and everywhere I got the same problem (mostly tested IE11).

Does some one of you, already had the problem or has a solution for that?

Because I ended with no solution :(.

Thanks!
Leitwerk

Comment: You really need to be more specific to get any kind of help here.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, but I really don't know how... Because I can't find a problem :S